# bash iterate file list, except when empty

Tags: bash, parameter

I thought this would be simple - but it is proving more complex than I expected.

I want to iterate through all the files of a particular type in a directory, so I write this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in *.zip ; do
   echo current file is ${fname}
done
```

This works *as long as there is at least one matching file* in the directory. However if there are no matching files, I get this:

```
current file is *.zip
```

I then tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`ls *.zip`
for fname in "${FILES}" ; do
    echo current file is ${fname}
done
```

While the body of the loop does not execute when there are no files, I get an error from ls:

```
ls: *.zip: No such file or directory
```

How do I write a loop which cleanly handles no matching files?

Comment: Add `shopt -s nullglob` before running the for loop.

Comment: @cuolnglm: spookily this results in ls returning the name of the executing script rather than an empty list on this RHEL5 box (bash 3.2.25) if I do `FILES=`ls *.zip`; for fname in "${FILES}"...` but it does work as expected with `for fname in *.zip ; do....`

Comment: Use `for file in *.zip`, not `\`ls ...\``. @cuonglm's suggestion is so that `*.zip` expands to nothing when the pattern doesn't match any file. `ls` without arguments lists the current directory.

Comment: @cuonglm Post that as an answer

Comment: This question discusses why parsing the output of `ls` is generally to be avoided: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls); also see the link near the top of that page to BashGuide's [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) article.

Comment: @cuonglm: you were first to point out I should be using nullglob (getting the scriptname back was a result of the glob being expanded before the ls command was executed, hence 'ls *.zip' became simply 'ls'). Can you reporst your answer as a coment and I'll tick it off.

Comment: @symcbean: [chepner's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240004/38906) did. Don't use `ls`, just use a plain glob.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In `bash`, you can set the `nullglob` option so that a pattern that matches nothing "disappears", rather than treated as a literal string:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for fname in *.zip ; do
   echo "current file is ${fname}"
done
```

In POSIX shell script, you just verify that `fname` exists (and at the same time with `[ -f ]`, check it is a regular file (or symlink to regular file) and not other types like directory/fifo/device...):

```
for fname in *.zip; do
    [ -f "$fname" ] || continue
    printf '%s\n' "current file is $fname"
done
```

Replace `[ -f "$fname" ]` with `[ -e "$fname" ] || [ -L "$fname ]` if you want to loop over all the (non-hidden) files whose name ends in `.zip` regardless of their type.

Replace `*.zip` with `.*.zip .zip *.zip` if you also want to consider hidden files whose name ends in `.zip`.

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob` did not work for me on Ubuntu 17.04, but `[ -f "$fname" ] || continue` worked well.

Comment: @koppor It sounds like you aren't actually using `bash`.

Comment: +1 for a POSIX solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use find

```
export -f myshellfunc
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.zip' -exec bash -c 'myshellfunc "$0"' {} \;
```

You MUST export your shell function with `export -f` for this to work.
Now `find` executes `bash` which executes your shell function, and remains at the current dir level only.

Comment: Which recurses through subdirectories, and I want to invoke a bash function (not script) for the matches.

Comment: @symcbean I've edited to limit to single dir and handle bash functions

Answer (score 3):

```
set ./*                               #set the arg array to glob results
${2+":"} [ -e "$1" ] &&               #if more than one result skip the stat "$1"
printf "current file is %s\n" "$@"    #print the whole array at once

###or###

${2+":"} [ -e "$1" ] &&               #same kind of test
for    fname                          #iterate singly on $fname var for array
do     printf "file is %s\n" "$fname" #print each $fname for each iteration
done
```

In a comment here you mention invoking a function...

```
file_fn()
    if     [ -e "$1" ] ||               #check if first argument exists
           [ -L "$1" ]                  #or else if it is at least a broken link
    then   for  f                       #if so iterate on "$f"
           do : something w/ "$f"
           done
    else   command <"${1-/dev/null}"    #only fail w/ error if at least one arg
    fi

 file_fn *
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of:

```
FILES=`ls *.zip`
```

Try:

```
FILES=`ls * | grep *.zip`
```

This way if ls fails (which it does in your case) it will grep the failed output and return as a blank variable.

```
current file is      <---Blank Here
```

You can add some logic to this to make it return "No File Found"

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`ls * | grep *.zip`
if [[ $? == "0" ]]; then
    for fname in "$FILES" ; do
        echo current file is $fname
    done
else
    echo "No Files Found"
fi
```

This way if the previous command succeeded (exited with a 0 value) then it will print the current file, otherwise it would print "No Files Found"

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to add one more process (`grep`) rather than trying to fix the issue by using a better tool (`find`) or changing the relevant setting for the current solution (with `shopt -s nullglob`)

Comment: According to the OP's comment on their original post the `shopt -s nullglob` does not work. I tried `find` while verifying my answer and it kept failing. I think because of the export thing Dani said.